# google music/gallery picking up videos made by my app

Tags: android

This is the directory I'm saving media to:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyAppDir/";
```

The media (they're video files) are being picked up by google music and by the gallery. The strange thing is that it's only a few files that get picked up. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a file name *'.nomedia'* in that folder. This will tell Android not to show it's content in the Gallery.

You can also use a folder name that begins with a dot '.' but this will hide it from users browsing their file system as well and may not be what you want.